# Autofill In VBA based on the Value in another cell

Tags: excel, vba, autofill

I am attempting to autofill C3:G3 based on the values in column B being greater than 25,000. The autofill does not stop when the value in column B dips below 25,000 but instead flows down to the last active cell. Any ideas how to update the code in VBA?

```
Sub FillItUp()
Dim i As Long
i = 2
Do While Cells(i, "B").Value >= 25000
    If Cells(i, "B").Value >= i Then
        Range("C2:G2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("c3" & i & ":G" & i), _ 
        Type:=xlFillDefault
End If
i = i + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have a typo in your question? `Range("C2:G2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("c3" & i & ":G" & i)` - first of all, the destination has to include the source, and second, `"C3" & i` looks problematic.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? You normally don't need a loop to autofill.

Comment: I need c:g to autofill as long as the value in column B is greater than 25000